# Android App is not loading in AVD properly

Tags: android, android-emulator, cordova, emulation

my app is just at starting mode but does not load completely
the Logcat Message is :
"Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."
please help me ..

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.d("in on create", "before thread");
        new handler().start();
    }

    private class handler extends Thread {

        @Override
        public synchronized void start() {

            super.start();
            Log.d("in handler ", "inside start");

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @deepak see this example

Comment: u r saying correctly but there is a problem when i create a class named MainActivity. then a layout have to be created in r.java file but it is reverted back as i can see in console output

Answer (score 0):

If you really think that is doing all of the work on UI Thread. then just do create a Thread object and make your function calls in its run()

```
Thread t=new Thread();
t.start();


public void run(){

makeYourFunctionCallHere();
}
```

or you can use ASysncTask if doing some network operation.

Comment: you ca use in the launcher activity itself

Answer (score 0):

Use Async Task to run the tasks in background.

Here is a example :

http://android-am.blogspot.in/2012/10/async-task-with-progress-dialog-in.html

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if you are doing some network operation, Bitmap downloading and setting on ImageViews iteratively. This consumes much memory to be done So this kind of issues raised.

In case of Bitmap downloading and setting to imageView you should resize images as per imageView (eg. list image-icons in ListView).